# Switch case is not working in Reactjs

Tags: forms, reactjs, dynamic, switch-statement

I have a json and I'm trying to display a form using the json data. I tried to display the indexes using the Switch case, so based on the html control type the index will be displayed. Below is my code

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var DATA = {
"indexList": [{
        "Label": "Name",
        "Type": "text",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "",
        "Values": {
            "Key": "",
            "Value": ""
        },
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "required",
        "maxLength":"16",
        "minLength":"7",
        "format":"Alphanumeric",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    },
    {
        "Label": "Select Language",
        "Type": "dropdown",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "English",
        "Values": [{
            "Key": "option1",
            "Value": "English"
        },{
            "Key": "option2",
            "Value": "Spanish"
        }],
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "Y",
        "maxLength":"",
        "minLength":"",
        "format":"",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    },

    {
        "Label": "Type",
        "Field_Type": "radio",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "",
        "Values": [{
            "Key": "option1",
            "Value": "Form1"
        }, {
            "Key": "option2",
            "Value": "Form2"
        }, {
            "Key": "option3",
            "Value": "Form3"
        },{
            "Key": "option4",
            "Value": "Form4"
        },{
            "Key": "option5",
            "Value": "Form5"
        }],
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "Y",
        "maxLength":"",
        "minLength":"",
        "format":"",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    }
]
};

var Menu = React.createClass({

renderForm: function () {

    var data = DATA.indexList;
    console.log(data);
    return data.map(group =>{
        return <div>
                <label for={group.Label}>{group.Label}</label>
                <div>
                    switch(group.Type) {
                        case 'text':
                        return <input className={group.cssClassName} 
                                      id={group.Label} 
                                      placeholder={group.Placeholder}
                                      {group.Mandatory}/>

                        case 'dropdown':
                        return <select className={group.cssClassName}>
                                    <option value="">{group.Placeholder}</option>
                                    <option for="let values of group.Values.value">{values}</option>
                                </select>


                        case 'radio':
                        return <div className={group.Type}>
                                    <div for="let value of group.Values">
                                        <label><input
                                        name="radios"/>{value}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        case 'chekbox'
                        return <div className={group.Type}>
                                    <div for="let value of group.Values">
                                        <label><input name="checkbox"/>{value}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    }
                </div>
               </div>
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (    
        <div className="container">
            <br/>
            <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Form</div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-5">
                                    {this.renderForm()}
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
)}
});

module.exports = Menu
```

With the above code Im getting an error "Unexpexcted token" and the error is pointing towards the "case". Can anyone help to resolve the issue, Im new to react and Im not able to resolve this issue. Any syntax error in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to put `{}`, use this:

```
<div>
 {

 }
```

To use any `javascript` code inside `HTML` element we need to use `{}`.

**Note**: We can't directly use `if-else/switch` statement inside `JSX`, use either `ternary operator` or call a function from `JSX` and use `if-else/switch` inside that.

Reference: http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Check the working example:

```js
var DATA = {
"indexList": [{
        "Label": "Name",
        "Type": "text",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "",
        "Values": {
            "Key": "",
            "Value": ""
        },
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "Y",
        "maxLength":"16",
        "minLength":"7",
        "format":"Alphanumeric",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    },
    {
        "Label": "Select Language",
        "Type": "dropdown",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "English",
        "Values": [{
            "Key": "option1",
            "Value": "English"
        },{
            "Key": "option2",
            "Value": "Spanish"
        }],
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "Y",
        "maxLength":"",
        "minLength":"",
        "format":"",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    },

    {
        "Label": "Type",
        "Type": "radio",
        "Regex": "",
        "Default_Val": "",
        "Values": [{
            "Key": "option1",
            "Value": "Form1"
        }, {
            "Key": "option2",
            "Value": "Form2"
        }, {
            "Key": "option3",
            "Value": "Form3"
        },{
            "Key": "option4",
            "Value": "Form4"
        },{
            "Key": "option5",
            "Value": "Form5"
        }],
        "Validtion Msg": "",
        "Script": "",
        "Mandatory": "Y",
        "maxLength":"",
        "minLength":"",
        "format":"",
        "cssClassName": "form-control",
        "Placeholder": ""
    }
]
};

var Menu = React.createClass({

_renderElement: function(group){
   switch(group.Type){
                        case 'text':
                        return <input className={group.cssClassName} 
                                      id={group.Label} 
                                      placeholder={group.Placeholder}
                                      required={group.Mandatory == 'Y'? true: false}/>

                        case 'dropdown':
                        return <select className={group.cssClassName}>
                                    <option value="">{group.Placeholder}</option>
                                    {group.Values.map(el => <option key={el.Key} for="let values of group.Values.value">{el.Value}</option>)}
                                </select>


                        case 'radio':
                        return <div className={group.Type}>
                                    <div for="let value of group.Values">
                                    {group.Values.map(el=> <label key={el.Value}><input
                                        name="radios"/>{el.Value}</label>)}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        case 'checkbox':
                        return <div className={group.Type}>
                                    <div for="let value of group.Values">
                                        <label><input name="checkbox"/>{value}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    }
},

renderForm: function () {

    var data = DATA.indexList;
    return data.map(group =>{
        return <div>
                <label for={group.Label}>{group.Label}</label>
                <div>
                {
                   this._renderElement(group)
                }
                </div>
               </div>
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (    
        <div className="container">
            <br/>
            <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Form</div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div className="col-xs-5">
                                
                
                                    {this.renderForm()}
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
)}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Menu/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I have added { }, but still i'm getting the same error and pointing towards "Switch".

Comment: check the updated code, run the above snippet, we can't use switch or if else directly inside jsx, call a function and do that part inside that :)

Comment: Thanks for the above working code. Can you please help me to iterate the "Values" options in the above code. As of now its not working. I just want to display the radio button and dropdown options here. need to pick the list values and display the same. The current logic is not working and im getting error. Can you please help to loop the values and display it?

Comment: check the updated answer, by using `map` over values we can create the `html` elements :)

Comment: Hi I have updated the case 'text' where I need the 'required' property from json. as of now I have updated like {group.Mandatory} but this is showing a syntax error in the console "Unexpected token". How to resolve this?

Comment: @knbibin issue is you are not assigning any property to that value, include it like this: `required={group.Mandatory == 'Y'? true: false}` check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`swithc-case` should be within braces

```
renderForm: function() {

  var data = DATA.indexList;
  console.log(data);
  return data.map(group => {
    return <div >
      < label
    for = {
      group.Label
    } > {
      group.Label
    } < /label> < div >{
      switch (group.Type) {
        case 'text':
          return <input className = {
            group.cssClassName
          }
          id = {
            group.Label
          }
          placeholder = {
            group.Placeholder
          }
          />

        case 'dropdown':
                    return;

      }} < /div> < /div>
  });
},
```